# Data base records to grid convertion

Tags: algorithm

We have faced with a problem when we need to convert data base records into a grid.

Here is what i mean by that:

```
u1 | q1 | a12
u1 | q2 | a22
...
u1 | qN | a1N
u2 | q1 | a21
u2 | q2 | a22
...
u2 | qK | a2K
u3 | q1 | a31
u3 | q2 | a32
...
u3 | qL | a3L
...
uM | q1 | aM1
uM | q2 | aM2
...
uM | qR | aMR

M ~ 1000
N,K,L,R ~ 50

===============>

 #  q1   q2   ...  qN   qK   qL   qR
u1  a11  a12  ...  a1N  -    -    -
u2  a21  a22  ...  -    a2K  -    -
u3  a31  a32  ...  -    -    a3L  -
...
uM  aM1  aM2  ...  -    -    -    aMR
```

So matrix at the top reflects a record set from data base,
ordered by u (user), q (question).
Each user might have different number of question answers.

The bottom matrix is what we need to convert to which is some kind of a grid.
As you can see some users might or might not have some question / answer pairs which is there will be some gaps. And the "structure" of these gaps
can very (so not exactly first 2 question/answer will be fetched first).

While as we already have some working algorithm it rather smells since traverses a data set twice.

Maybe somebody has an idea how to make such a conversion most efficiently.

p.s.
Unfortunately we cannot change condition of the problem meaning that
the matrix at the top has to be of this shape and problem cannot be resolved by means of additional calls to db.
The use case is reporting environment which only allow to do one query and then post process data into what we need.

Comment: so i would expect an answer using a common data structs as: array, hash map, etc

Comment: Show us the smelly algorithm. We'll hold our noses.

Comment: Do you have the grid data structure, and you're just looking for an algorithm to read the database and produce calls like `Grid[u1][q1] = a11`, or are you asking for the grid data structure as well?

Comment: actually, the output data structure has to be an array.
because we will pas to next to the lib which will generate an Excel file form it.

but the algorithm we're looking for should not do nested loops (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
import os
from sets import Set

data = r"""u1 | q1 | a12
u1 | q2 | a22
u1 | qN | a1N
u2 | q1 | a21
u2 | q2 | a22
u2 | qK | a2K
u3 | q1 | a31
u3 | q2 | a32
u3 | qL | a3L
uM | q1 | aM1
uM | q2 | aM2
uM | qR | aMR"""

s = data.split("\n")

users = {}
questions = Set()

for l in s:
    (u, q, a) = l.split("|")
    questions.add(q)
    if users.has_key(u):
        users[u][q] = a
    else:
        users[u] = {q:a}

# print header 
str = "%5s " % " "
for q in questions:
    str += "%5s" % q
print str

# print the table
for u in users:
    str = ""
    str += "%5s " % u
    for q in questions:
        if users[u].has_key(q):
            str += "%5s" % users[u][q]
        else:
            str += "  -  "
    print str
```

The output looks like this:

```
>>> 
        q1   qR   q2   qK   qN   qL 
  u1    a12  -    a22  -    a1N  -  
  u2    a21  -    a22  a2K  -    -  
  uM    aM1  aMR  aM2  -    -    -  
  u3    a31  -    a32  -    -    a3L
```

Comment: well, i wouldn't call it efficient.

Comment: first there is a loop through input "s" data set.
on each iteration there is another one: has_key

then at the end once more the same iteration with the difference it became "users" and on each iteration, instead of traversing just "has_key", it is also done on every question iteration.
i'm not good at estimating running time but two loops with nested loops in turn doesn't seem like efficient.

basically we have quite the same, maybe a bit optimized